# Binding Model in nodejs with express-cassandra

Tags: express-cassandra

I just want to apply the Bind of the following tutorial and apply on my project:
http://express-cassandra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/

My current model is on models directory called UserModel.js:

```
module.exports = {
    fields:{
        name    : "text",
        surname : "text",
        age     : "int",
        created : "timestamp"
    },
    key:["name"]
}
```

And the index.js bind the last model:

```
var models = require('express-cassandra');

models.setDirectory( __dirname + '/models').bind(
    {
        clientOptions: {
            contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'],
            protocolOptions: { port: 9042 },
            keyspace: 'pop',
            queryOptions: {consistency: models.consistencies.one}
        },
        ormOptions: {
            defaultReplicationStrategy : {
                class: 'SimpleStrategy',
                replication_factor: 1
            },
            migration: 'safe'
            createKeyspace:true
        }
    },
    function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;


    }
);

    module.exports{
models:models
}
```

It goes Ok with the connection, but after the succesfull connect to casandra db(localhost:9042), It show me a message :"Keyspace user_schema does not exist"
Can anyone give me an idea to fix that? may be doesnt load the model, But It seems ok, But before to load the model It doesnt recognise the Keyspace, And It is the right Keyspace of my db

Comment: Looks like you are missing a comma after migration: 'safe'

Answer (score 0):

I updated the express-cassandra and now It Works, issue was the compatibility